# ds18b20 One wire address format translate from arduino to debian

Tags: arduino, debian, beagleboneblack, 1wire

I recorded all the addresses of most of my ds18b20's with arduino, and they look different when plugged into Beaglebone Black running debian. Is there a way I can translate them to how they look on debian? I can't test them all since most are installed in my prototype..

arduino = '0x28, 0x9D, 0xB6, 0xAB, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E'

debian = '28-000005abb69d'

Comment: Other than reversing all but the first byte?

Comment: oh wow i didn't see that at all! that first byte is the sensor type, so that makes sense it stays first. what about the 3E? can you explain that?

Comment: Part of me is saying "checksum", but I don't know the algorithm. But it shouldn't matter if you're translating in the lossy direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just converting the address.

`0x28` is the sensor type (Programmable Digital Thermometer).

`0x3E` is the [1-Wire check-sum](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/27) (slightly different than a normal CRC8).

`0x9D, 0xB6, 0xAB, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00` is the actual address in big-endian mode.

*As a note, the raw address is typically formatted as `[CRC][Serial][Family Code]`, so it's strange that your Arduino is presenting it in a flipped format `[Family Code][Serial][CRC]`, but not flipping the value within the serial attribute.*

Comment: I don't quite understand check sums. Are they constant? I thought they were individual sensor reading specific...

Comment: The check-sum on the address is constant, but only because the address is constant.  You still need to run a check-sum on the address after reading it to make sure there wasn't an issue with transmission, because in the real world you won't already know the address, so the only way to tell if it was transmitted correctly is to calculate the check-sum.  If you include the check-sum value in the check-sum calculation, the value should come out 0.  If any other value comes out, then you have an error and you should rerun the operation or search.